# docker image for dbt-snowflake

Tags: docker, bitbucket-pipelines, cicd, dbt, fishtown-analytics

How can I run dbt commands within a bitbucket pipeline? What is the correct docker image that I should be using if I wanted to use dbt-snowflake? I tried `fishtownanalytics/dbt`and `joevandyk/dbt`both:

```
pipelines:
  custom: 
    test-dbt:
      - step:
          name: 'Test'
          image: fishtownanalytics/dbt
          script:
            - cd dbt_4flow
            - dbt compile
```

but I still get this error:

```
+ dbt compile
bash: dbt: command not found
```

Comment: could you show your Dockerfile please ?

Comment: I don't have a docker file of my own? I am just using ```image: fishtownanalytics/dbt``` https://hub.docker.com/u/fishtownanalytics and https://hub.docker.com/r/joevandyk/dbt @dnej

Comment: when I try to pull the image locally using `docker pull fishtownanalytics/dbt`, I am not able, but by adding the version: `docker pull fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0`, I am able, could you try adding the version in you bitbucket script ?

Comment: fishtownanalytics/dbt is depreciated. Instead use this: `docker pull ghcr.io/dbt-labs/dbt-core:1.1.2` and check here for a full list; https://github.com/orgs/dbt-labs/packages?visibility=public

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I try to pull the image locally using

`docker pull fishtownanalytics/dbt`

I am not able, but by adding the version:

`docker pull fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0`

It's working.

You need to add the version to your bitbucket pipeline, so you will be able to  do it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, you need to specify the version for fishtownanalytics.

```
image: fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0
```

Here's a full tutorial for creating a similar pipeline: https://medium.com/geekculture/automate-dbt-runs-with-bitbucket-pipelines-3e7528ff991f